# InDesign CC Image Caption Numbering Bug

Tags: adobe-indesign

I don't know if it's a bug, but I created a document with images and captions. Theses captions are actually text frames with custom "list" to get the numbering working and taken in consideration every time I create a new text frame (continuous numbering).

The problem is, that when I group the image with the text frame, and then anchor the group to the text, the number of the caption change. 
For example, if i have Caption N° 11 grouped with an image then anchored to text, the number goes from 11 to 4 with no reason ... The first three images are grouped with their captions and anchored to the text but that works fine...
I have recorded my screen, please see here: https://youtu.be/Ftjgcx1Fn5E

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The caption takes the number of the paragraphs in that text-thread. (it become 4th paragraph on the text-thread, that's why it takes 1-4)

i think that you have to anchor all the captions in same text-thread.

Otherwise, you can use Text Variables (Live Captions i.e)
You can edit the metadata info of each photo and you can put auto-generated-captions. look at here - http://blogs.adobe.com/indesignpost/2010/10/setting-up-live-captions-in-indesign-cs5/